# Using Cordova and his plugins on a remote url

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I like to use Cordova and InAppBrowser plugin with a remote webapp, on oppening my application load an external webapp like this `<content src="http://mywebapp.domain.com" />` but with this method i dont have access to any plugins.

So i also tried with jquery :

**config.xml**

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

**index.html :**

```
<div id="remoteframe"></div>
$('#remoteframe"').load('http://mywebapp.domain.com');
```

With this i have access to cordova and all the plugins but the rooting inside of http://mywebapp.domain.com dont work anymore (no css, no js, no route..) and the method look very "dirty".

Is there a proper way to do this ?

Comment: the 2nd line of your `index.html` contains syntax errors.

Comment: Yes it was just for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally found, I had to include this on my remote page (http://mywebapp.domain.com) :

`<script src="/js/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="/js/inappbrowser.js"></script>`

And apparently `cordova_plugins.js` must be in the /js/ folder to (same folder as cordova.js).

For multiplaforms you may need to change with the right cordova.js.

Comment: it work on android and ios but you have to do deserve the good cordova.js, i doing it by checking the user agent, ex : http://pastebin.com/jSzvwSZz (dont forget to put cordova_plugin.js in both folder).

Comment: Thanks! Can you post an update if this approach passed the iOS app store approval?

Comment: @VladStirbu, I have published an app to the App Store that uses this technique.  No problems during the review process.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the script loading solution/? Is it loading that cordova.js and inappbrowser.js locally from storage on the device or did you have to copy those into the assets of your server side web application?  Also, does it now successfully load your server-side javascript and css referenced in your web pages?

Comment: @SteveMadere here is how my index.php (mywebapp.domain.com/index.php) look like pastebin.com/7MJh9uas

Comment: @tahola:  Thanks, I understood that this is how your php looks.  My question is this:  Did you have to copy all of those javascript assets (cordova.js, cordova/*.js etc) from the cordova build tree to your PHP server's filesystem or is there some magic in the cordova inAppBrowser that is causing it to load those from the device where the browser is running even though they are apparently relative to the URL from which your php code was fetched?

Comment: Yes i had to copy all, the 4 cordova files included in the index.php are on my remote server with jquery, bootstrap etc...